# Is it possible to construct more than one stroke with different colors inside a single \pscustom?

Tags: pstricks

Is it possible to get the following output where the upper graph is red and the lower one is blue

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=17pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(5,2.5){6cm}{5cm}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange]
{
  \psplot{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
    \psplot{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
}
\psplot[linecolor=red]{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

only by using a single `\pscustom` inside `\psgraph` (no `\psplot` outside `\pscustom` for sure!)?

My attempt is as follows but it fails because both graphs are blue.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=17pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(5,2.5){6cm}{5cm}
\pscustom[linestyle=none]
{
  \psplot{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
    \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=red]
    \gsave
  \psplot{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
    \fill[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange]
    \grestore
    \psplot[liftpen=2]{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
    \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=blue]
}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to construct more than one stroke with different colors inside a single `\pscustom`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=17pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(5,2.5){6cm}{5cm}
\pscustom[linestyle=none]
{
  \psplot{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
    \gsave
    \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=red]
  \psplot{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
    \fill[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange]
    \grestore
    \newpath
    \psplot[liftpen=2]{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
    \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=blue]
}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation how the code work? Why do we need to swap the first 3 rows? And why do we need a new path?

Comment: @Bugbusters I guessed and got lucky:-) I can't really remember any pstricks but in postscript if you want to draw two paths with different stroke settings you need a newpath operator somewhere so I guessed there was a pstricks `\newpath` command and guessed putting it there might help....

Comment: that is wrong, because "one path -- one stroke". The read line has only the half width because the filling area is above the other half of the line.

Comment: @Bugbusters if in doubt do what Herbert says:-)

Comment: @Herbert yes I suppose subconsciously I noticed that and ignored it, I assume the red line could be stroked  last to get back on top of the fill?

Answer (score 0):

Using `\pscustom` with `gsave-grestore` seems to be overkill.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=17pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=1pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(5,2.5){6cm}{5cm}
\pscustom[linestyle=none]
{
  \gsave  
    \psplot{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
    \psplot{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
    \fill[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange]
  \grestore 
  \newpath
  \psplot{1}{4}{sqrt(x)}
  \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=red]
  \newpath
  \psplot{4}{1}{sqrt(x/2)}
  \stroke[linestyle=solid,linecolor=blue]
}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```